# using logical quantifiers to write that f approaching infinity DOES NOT tend to infinity

Tags: analysis, limits, quantifiers

Is this the same as writing that the limit of f as f approaches $\infty$ is L?
i.e.:
$\forall \space \epsilon > 0 \space \exists \space c \space \forall \space x>c : |f(x) - L|< \epsilon$

Comment: This doesn't say just that $f$ does not tend to infinity, it says the stronger statement that $f$ tends to $L$.

Comment: It looks like you mean as $x\to\infty$, $f(x)\not\to\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that $f(x)\not\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ is not the same thing as saying
$f(x)\to L$ as $x\to\infty$.  $f$ may not tend to any limit. The first statement with quantifiers

$$\exists M>0\,\forall r\in\Bbb R\,\exists x>r\,f(x)\le M.$$

To see why this is, consider the statement $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. Formally this is

$$\forall M>0\,\exists r\in\Bbb R\,\forall x>r\,f(x)>M.$$

This can be informally translated as no matter how large an $M$ we pick, we can always find a real number $r$ so that the value of $f$ exceeds $M$ for any real number larger than $r$.

When the sentence is negated each $\forall$ changes to $\exists$ and vice versa and the statement after the quantifiers is negated. That's how I got the first statement.

Informally it says that there is an $M$ so that no matter how large we pick $r$ there will be an $x>r$ for which the value of $f$ is no bigger than $M$.

Comment: I agree with one exception, I would consider "tending to negative infinity" to not contradict "not tending to infinity", as such I would consider $\lim_{x\to\infty} -x$ to "not tend to infinity", yet there is no subsequence of $f(n)=-n$ that is bounded.  Consider removing the absolute value sign in the final expression.  In the extended real case, $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are separate entities, but otherwise in the extended complex case no distinction is made between the two and your definition should hold.

Comment: Ah, good point. I will fix that.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick and useful replies! However, I am having a hard time understanding where M and f(y) come from. I am a bit new to using logical quantifiers.

Comment: The $y$ was a mistake.  I've corrected it.  I'll edit my answer to explain more.